# livewire no actualiza valor

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8, laravel-livewire, livewire

estoy empezando a usar livewire y prácticamente no se nada.

el problema es que no actualizar mi contador sin recargar la pagina:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando ingreso una nueva solicitud queda en el mismo valor hasta que reinicio la pagina...

```
   <?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Rrppsolicitudes;
use App\Models\Dias;
use Auth;

class Counter extends Component
{


    public $count = 0;

    public function render(Request $request)
    {

       $evento = request()->segments()[1];
        $rrpp = Auth::user()->id;
        $contador = Rrppsolicitudes::where('evento_id' , $evento)->where('rrpp_id', $rrpp)->whereNull('estado')->count('id');
    
        return view('livewire.counter',compact('contador'));
    }
}
```

balde:

```
<div style="background-color: #ff4040;
width: 117px;
font-size: 16px;
color: white;
border-radius: 15px;" class="text-center mx-auto">{{$contador}} Solicitudes</div>
```

**cual seria el problema?**

Answer (score 0):

para lo que necesitas puedes usar la directiva :pool
adjunto la documentación
[Livewire :poll](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/polling)

Comment: Hola Javier, gracias por tu colaboración, te sugiero que 
 veas [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para evitar votos negativos y/o que tu repuesta sea eliminada.